# Lame compress mp3 files recursively

Tags: 14.04, mp3, lame

I want to compress my entire music collection (a copy of it, actually) using lame. So naturally, there are folders within folders and possible weird characters in file names. *I used the graphical **soundconverter** as well, but didn't like it as it has predefined bit rates.*

What I've tried so far:

```
$ find . -name "*.mp3" | lame -b 160
```

and

```
$  find . -name "*.mp3" > list 
$ cat list | lame -b 160
```

and

```
$ lame -b 160 < list
```

All of these give me usage error. What is the right way to do it? Also, if there's a way to ***overwrite the original file***, I'll be too happy.

Comment: `cat $file | $program` is equivalent to `$program <$file`, except for the unnecessary `cat` invocation (and the overhead associated with kicking off an extra process, etc). In general, you should avoid the first form. `find . | $program` is similarly preferable to `find . >$file; $program <$file;` in that it avoids creating an unnecessary file, _unless_ you'll be reusing the list, in which case it might be preferable to write it out to a file first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lame` cannot read in filenames from input. You will have to use `find`'s `-exec` or `xargs` to run it over each file found:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3' -exec lame -b {} \;
```

If a second filename isn't specified, `lame` will attach another `.mp3` to the given filename and write to that file. `lame` does not support writing to the same file. You'll have to convert to another file, then copy it over the original file:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3' -exec sh -c 'lame -b 160 "$0" "$0"-160 && mv "$0"-160 "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: Superb answer! Crystal-clear explanation and a neat solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try a the following:

Start with removing whitespaces from the file names since these seems to cause trouble:

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.mp3"); do rename "s/\s+/_/g" *; done
```

Execute a loop and traverse through all files:

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.mp3"); do lame -b 160 "$f" tmp && mv tmp "$f"; done
```

Now you will overwrite the original files with those created by lame.

Comment: Actually I wish to retain the directory structure as I organize my music by directories.

Comment: Okay, we'll just add the find statement in the second query. I'll change the code.

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting errors like `could not find "./01.", etc. I guess the spaces are causing a problem. How to overcome that?

Comment: Is removing/replacing the whitespaces an option or should they be preserved?

Comment: I think I'll be fine with underscores. But I'm hoping dots, etc., won't cause trouble.

Comment: @dotslash
OK! Added a loop to replace whitespaces as well. Hope everything works according to plan now!

Comment: Nope, sorry. Now the `mv` command is breaking: mv: `cannot stat ‘./02.’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Too’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Much’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘To’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Bear.mp3’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Should have tested it myself first, sorry!
Now it is correct.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! Please don't mind but I accepted another answer. I just think it's more compact. :-)

Comment: If you need to loop over the output of `find`, a `for` loop over `$()` is the wrong way.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.  It will break on filenames with spaces, for example.  This is why `find -exec` exists, even though it's cumbersome to use when you have to do `-exec sh -c ...`

Comment: Instead of invoking `find` (`for file in $(find . -name "*.mp3")`), you could `shopt -s globstar` (for `bash`) and use `for file in **/*.mp3`.